# type mismatch; found : Long required: Int

Tags: scala

I have a method that is supposed to return an Long.
But I get an error : 
`**type mismatch; found : Long required: Int**`

Here is the method:

```
def getRandom_IMEI(from : Long,to : Long) : Long = {
    if (from < to)
        return from + new scala.util.Random().nextInt(Math.abs(to - from));
    return from - new scala.util.Random().nextInt(Math.abs(to - from));
   }
```

and when I make a call to this method like this :

```
def IMEI() : String ={
    var str: String =""
    var rand:Long = 0
    rand = functest.getRandom_IMEI(350000000000000,355000000000000)  //error
    str=rand.toString()
    return str
  }
```

I have this error:

```
    Multiple markers at this line:
        ◾integer number too large
        ◾integer number too large
```

Comment: Use `val` not `var` in your IMEI function - you''re only assigning them once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out being sure what your goal is, my eye catch following things.

As you write, error with the following line:

```
rand = functest.getRandom_IMEI(350000000000000,355000000000000)  //error
```

you need to make it long by adding `L` at the end of Long number.

```
rand = functest.getRandom_IMEI(350000000000000L,355000000000000L)
```

But you still can clean your `IMEI()` method so it looks like this, there is no need to `var` and you do not need to declare `str` since your are returning string:

```
def IMEI(): String = {
  val rand = getRandom_IMEI(355000000000000L, 350000000000000L)
  rand.toString
}
```

> Note: long type is specified by appending L or l suffix to the
>   litera ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax))

the other thing is your `getRandom_IMEI` did not work for me as well, I did some thing simple like:

```
def getRandom_IMEI(from: Long, to: Long): Long = {
  if (from < to) {
    from + new scala.util.Random(to - from).nextLong()
  } else {
    from - new scala.util.Random(to - from).nextLong()
  }
}
```

Since I am do not know your final goal, but you can also use `nextInt()` instead of `.nextLong()`. But perhaps so you have a working code and you can do it your way. I have tested and works.

- And general rule in Scala you do not need to end each line with `;` like Java
- You do not need to return, it will return automatically the last statement, so you easily remove the return from your second method and just keep `str`

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues, one is with your Long literals. 
the Random.nextInt method expects an Int argument, but to and from are Long and so is their absolute difference. 
If you happen to know the difference will fit in an Int you can force the result into an Int with an explicit conversion.

When you just type a number in code it is interpreted as an Int but the numbers in your code are too large to be an Int therefor you must put an "L" suffix on each number (lowercase l works as well).

As a side note multiple return statements are considered bad form, and are unnecessary. I would remove both return statements and add an else
In the second method you can get rid of the last return statement and also the val assignment.